# How can I control my fans with SpeedFan? Doesn't show anything

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, temperature, speedfan

I have a problem. My laptop gets really hot every time... Last time it was around 120 degrees. I need to control my fans with SpeedFan. But the problem is that my laptop doesn't see the fans.

My specs:

- Acer Travelmate p633-M
- Intel Core I3

I don't know more specs. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Found this fan made utility...
http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/711908-acer-7551g-fan-control-utility-fixes-overheating.html

Comment: Im sorry but my laptop give's a weird .xml code and it wont install it.. Whatever i do, he give the hole time a complete error...!